# Parallel extension enchancement

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net

As suggested in comments [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121446/multithreading-extensions) I created a new topic for next version. I edited a bit original code, added exception processing and optimization, that first N = 1/core count tasks are processed on main thread.

```
public static void Foreach<T>(ICollection<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    var toBeProcessedOnMainThread = (int) Math.Ceiling((double)source.Count / Environment.ProcessorCount);
    var countdown = new CountdownEvent(source.Count - toBeProcessedOnMainThread);
    ConcurrentBag<Exception> exceptionsBag = null;
    var onMainThread = source.Take(toBeProcessedOnMainThread);
    foreach (var item in source.Skip(toBeProcessedOnMainThread))
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            var closure = (T)state;
            try
            {
                action(closure);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ref exceptionsBag, countdown, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                countdown.Signal();
            }
        }, item);
    }
    foreach (T value in onMainThread)
    {
        try
        {
            action(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ref exceptionsBag, countdown, ex);
        }
    }
    countdown.Wait();
    if (exceptionsBag != null)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptionsBag);
}

private static void HandleException(ref ConcurrentBag<Exception> exceptions, object syncRoot, Exception ex)
{
    if (exceptions == null)
        lock (syncRoot)
            if (exceptions == null)
                exceptions = new ConcurrentBag<Exception>();

    exceptions.Add(ex);
}
```

I do lock `countdown` because I do not want to introduce another local variable, and it locks only once and only if exception occurs. Normally it won't be called an thus won't be locked.

Comment: I can't help but think that this would all be simpler if you used a `Parallel.ForEach()` instead of directly invoking threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RubberDuck is right. It looks like you are reinventing the wheel. Unless you are doing this whole thing for educational purposes, you should rather use TPL. `ForEach` method does exactly what you are trying to do and most likely does a better job at splitting processing power between the tasks:

```
Parallel.ForEach(source, action);
```

Regarding your implementation: `CountdownEvent` implements `IDisposable`, so you should dispose it after you are done using it. Or wrap it into a `using` block.

Also this code is the kind of micro-optimization you should avoid:

```
if (exceptions == null)
    lock (syncRoot)
        if (exceptions == null)
            exceptions = new ConcurrentBag<Exception>();
```

Is `new ConcurrentBag` call a bottleneack of this method? Does it take anywhere near as much resources as calling an `Action` method? ["No? Then don't introduce additional concurrency!" :)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55335/24349)  Just call `ConcurrentBag<Exception> exceptionsBag = new ConcurrentBag<Exception>();` and forget about synchronization. Or at least follow Eric's advice in above link and use `Lazy<T>`.